# Flutter Error: The getter 'StrokeAlign' isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter

After updating flutter to 3.7 I am getting the above error.

```
Error: The getter 'StrokeAlign' isn't defined for the class
```

What has changed recently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a breaking change in flutter 3.7 [Release Notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.7.0).

To fix change `StrokeAlign.center` to `BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter`